# JavaScript doesn't run in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to find out how to run `JavaScript` in `Django` to create chained forms. But at the first I want to find out how to even run `JavaScript`. I've created a simple `main.js` file which is in `static` forder.

I've added a path to `main.js` into the head of `html`. And the script have to run when the page is loaded (just to be sure that I can step forward).

I've put `alert` on the beginning of the function so I can see whether the `js` has been run. But I can't see no `alert` nor `js` in `chrome inspect`.

Could you guys tell me where is the problem?

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("OK")
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-possible-levels/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {language: $('#id_language').val()},
    })
})
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
    <script src="{% static  "js/main.js" %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ language_form }}
            <button value="Update" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

View:

```
@login_required                                                                                      
def create_order(request):                                                                           
    language_form = LanguageLevelForm(request.POST or None)                                                                                                                                    
    return render(request,'auth/jobs/create-job-test.html',context={'language_form':language_form})
```

EDIT: The `main.js` seems to be executed but it does not `alert` anything. I've checked `inspect` (and I've tried to put semicolon after `alert('ok')`) :

[image]

Comment: View the page source in your browser. Can you see the script src and click it?

Comment: No! So there is a problem with block head! Thanks, but still... now, main.js is visible in inspect but I can't see any alert...

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after your alert. Also the ajax will probably fail as you need to send a csrf token in the POST requests data.

Comment: JavaScript never runs in Django...It's a client-side language that runs in the browser. As a result, use your browser console to determine whether or not the JS file has actually been loaded, and whether there are any JS errors.

Comment: I've updated my question. Georgina, I'm not there yet, I want just to make alert work to be sure that I can move forward.

Comment: @rnevius I've checked that. Updated question, you can see the pic of inspect. It is loaded but not executed probably...

Comment: Are you working on the local Django server? This is a long shot but your script returns a 304 so a cached version of the script is served. Try pressing F12 in your chrome browser then right click the refresh button and select 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'. Could you also provide your folder structure and the section of settings.py which points to your static path?

Comment: This doesn't helped but I've found in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Please see my revised answer about Jquery then

Answer (score 1):

Your `{% load static %}` should be `{% load staticfiles %}`. After that try refreshing the page the way I described in my comment. BTW Are you actually including JQuery? Your question is about JavaScript. You should try to use a vanilla JavaScript alert before adding JQuery code just to troubleshoot it. If you can get that working try adding this to your `<head>`

```
 <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> use CDN link if you dont have the file downloaded

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have the path to the js file wrong.if your project folder has 2 folders inside (one with html files and 1 with Js files) then on your path with the ../ you go up one level on your folder and then go inside your javascript folder to find the file. So instead of

```
 <script src="{% static  "js/main.js" %}"></script>
```

write

```
 <script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: In my flask application (which is similar to django) i used a static folder and inside the static folder put the js folder. so the path would be something like that:
 <script src="../static/js/main.js"></script>